# F5 doesn't work RIGHT on my webapp

Tags: html, angularjs, redirect, refresh, f5

i have a strange problem:

we have to make a project in IT, therefore we use AngularJS.
The problem is, when I use F5 for refresh, the page loads, but it is not able to show the right content again. There's just background and my title, everything in my UI-VIEW isn't there. 
We have Login-Page with redirecting:

```
     app.run(function($rootScope, $location, sessionFactory) {
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', 
    function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
        let loggedIn = sessionFactory.isAuthenticated();
        if (toState.authenticate && !loggedIn) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $state.go('login');
        }
    });
```

});

without this redirecting block, F5 works.
Otherwise I have to go to Login-Page and login again to get it work again.

I'm sorry guys, I'm new at programming. So if there's any code you need, just let me know. Hope someone can help.

UPDATE: this is our authentification_service.js
a group member wrote it. Does it help?

```
      var app = angular.module('TheApp');

    /**
    * This service manages sessions: Retrieving token from server and storing token data.
    */
    app.factory('sessionFactory', ['$http', 'jwtDecoder', function($http, jwtDecoder) {
var sessionFactory = {
    sessionData: null
};
sessionFactory.login = function(username, password) {
    //todo: encrypt password....
    var user = { username : username, password : password};
    // returns a POST request, success or error of that request
    // must be handled by the caller of the login function
    return $http({
             method: 'POST',
             url: 'rest/auth/login',
             data: user
    });
};
sessionFactory.logout = function() {
    return $http({
             method: 'POST',
             url: 'rest/auth/logout',
             data: this.sessionData
    });
}
sessionFactory.deleteSessionData = function() {
    this.sessionData = null;
}
sessionFactory.setSessionData = function(sessionData) {
    this.sessionData = {
        token: sessionData.token,
        userData: jwtDecoder.getUserData(sessionData.token) // holds user id, todo: permissions
    };
    console.log(this.sessionData.userData);
};
sessionFactory.getToken = function() {
    return this.sessionData.token;
};
sessionFactory.getUserId = function() {
    return this.sessionData.userData.userId;
}
sessionFactory.isAuthenticated = function() {
    return this.sessionData != null;
};
return sessionFactory;
}]);

/**
* This service injects authentification token in HTTP requests.
*/
app.factory('tokenInjector', ['$injector', function($injector) {
    var tokenInjector = {
        request: function(config) {
            // cannot use sessionFactory directly, because else Angular will spot a circular dependency -> error
            var sessionFactory = $injector.get('sessionFactory');
            // if the user is logged in, add an Authorization header (with token) to each http request
            if(sessionFactory.isAuthenticated()) {
                config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + sessionFactory.getToken();
                //config.url = config.url + "?token=" + sessionFactory.getToken(); // add token to request url
            }
            return config;
        }
    };
    return tokenInjector;
}]);
/**
* Decodes JWTs received from the server with a JWT deconding lib
* and returns a useable result.
*/
app.factory('jwtDecoder', function() {
    var jwtDecoder = {};
    // extracts all needed frontend user data from token
    jwtDecoder.getUserData = function(token) {
        var payload = jwt_decode(token);
        var userData = {
            userId: payload.userId //,
            //groupId: ?,
            //permissions: payload.permissions, // is array of perm
        };
        return userData;
    }
    return jwtDecoder;
})
```

Comment: It depends how your sessionFactory.isAuthenticated is working, it looks like it does not detect cookie/header information for session.

Comment: Yes, it looks to me also that your sessionFactory.isAuthenticated() function isn't using cookies properly.  You should post the code for this sessionFactory and maybe we can find the problem.  If you comment this line out and simply set the variable ``loggedIn = true``, and if it works, then you know where your problem is.

Comment: Thanks you both! Yes if I do this it works. Could you please tell me how to use cookies here?